# How do I make the function return a float list?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, f#-3.0, f#-fake

Please, how do I make this function return the value of every branch and leaf as a float list? I have tried several methods with Tail recursion but I am not able to return the head I cannot loop through the branch and leaf.

```
type 'a Tree =   | Leaf   of 'a   | Branch of 'a Tree * 'a Tree

let medianInTree (lst: float Tree) :float list=
    let rec medianInTree' (a : float Tree) acc = 
        match lst with
        | Leaf(n) -> n :: acc
        | Branch(Leaf(xx), Leaf(xs)) -> xx :: [xs] 
        | Branch(Leaf(x), Branch(Leaf(xx), Leaf(xs))) -> 
               let acc = medianInTree'(Leaf(x)) acc
               medianInTree' (Branch(Leaf(xx), Leaf(xs))) acc 
        | Branch(_, _) -> []
    medianInTree' lst []
```

Question: `medianInTree (Branch(Leaf(2.0), Branch(Leaf(3.0), Leaf(5.0))))`

I want this result: [2.0;3.0;5.0]

Answer (score 2):

using an accumulator, you can do something like this:

```
let flatten tree =
    let rec toList tree acc =
        match tree with
        | Leaf a -> a :: acc
        | Branch(left, right) ->
            let acc = toList left acc
            toList right acc
    toList tree [] |> List.rev
```

But doing so, the recursive call to process the left branch is not tail recursive.
To insure tail recursion while processing tree structures, you have to use [continuations](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-continuations/).

```
let flatten tree = 
    let rec toList tree cont acc =
        match tree with
        | Leaf a              -> cont (a :: acc)
        | Branch(left, right) -> toList left (fun l ->
                                    toList right (fun r -> 
                                        cont r) (cont l)) acc
    toList tree id [] |> List.rev
```

Which can be simplified as:

```
let flatten tree = 
    let rec toList tree cont acc =
        match tree with 
        | Leaf a               -> cont (a :: acc)
        | Branch (left, right) -> toList left (toList right cont) acc
    toList tree id [] |> List.rev
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gileCAD

Answer (score 1):

Your main bug is using `match` with `lst` instead of on `a`. I made it a bit simpler as well.

```
let medianInTree (lst: float Tree) :float list=
    let rec medianInTree' (a : float Tree)= 
        match a with
        | Leaf(n) -> [n]
        | Branch(l, r) -> (medianInTree' l) @ (medianInTree' r)
    medianInTree' lst
```

Comment: @Ringil while using concat, you do not need an accumulator: 
   `let rec toList = function  Leaf a -> [a] | Branch (l, r) -> toList l @ toList r`